# How can I implement Facebook login into my website locally?

Tags: facebook

I want to implement Facebook log-in (connect) into my website locally. I have looked at the documentation and I could not implement it myself. I have already created an App ID in Facebook. What should I change when I upload my website?

I have tried this example:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
```

and I get this error:

> `API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
>   URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.`

I have put `http://localhost:8080/` as my site URL. [The documentation says I can use this URL when developing locally](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/).

Note: I am developing using Apache, PHP, and javascript.

Comment: if i got you right, you want a facebook login locally on your web site ?
i think facebook policies forbids that due to fishing and spamming that it can be used for ???

Comment: <http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/> it says here we can use it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required domains for validation of the api? If you want to implement it on your local server then you will have to add the local address (that's what we do while creating canvas apps).

It's really worth reading [the detailed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/): you can implement the example and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.
Please make sure you are running this from the domain which you configured for you application on developers.facebook.com when you created you application!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
     <script>

        window.fbAsyncInit = function()
        {
            FB.init
            (
                {
                    appId   : "<<YOUR APP ID!>>",
                    status  : true,
                    cookie  : true,
                    oauth   : true
                }
            );
        };

        function login()
        {
            FB.login
            (
                function( response )
                {
                    if ( response.authResponse )
                    {
                        FB.api
                        (
                            "/me",
                            function( response )
                            {
                                document.getElementById( "profile_name" ).innerHTML = response.name;
                                document.getElementById( "profile_pic" ).src = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            );
        }

     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <a href="javascript:login();">Login</a>
    <img id="profile_pic"/>
    <div id="profile_name"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

find out the id address of your  system and instead of local host use your ip address give complete url of  page  where you are using login 
Ex http://192.168.0.10:8080/fb.html